# Get parent of class returned by closure without instanciating

Tags: php, class, oop, closures

How can I get a string containing the parent class' name of a class returned by a closure, without instantiating the class?

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}

$closure = function() {
    return new Bar;
};
```

How can I get a string('Foo') without instantiating Bar? I can not expect what `$closure` will return, as it will be inputted to my class.

I know I can get the parent class of another one by using the `ReflectionClass::getParentClass()` method.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Why not `$parent = get_parent_class($closure());`

Comment: @AbraCadaver This would instantiate `$closure`. Is it the only way ?

Comment: So far as I know but we'll see.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have not found any way, I will stick with your way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to achieve and why you cannot expect output from closure, but you can make something similar to this:

```
<?php

class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}

$closure = function() {
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass('Bar');
    return $reflection->getParentClass()->getName();
};

var_dump($closure());
```

Outputs:

```
string 'Foo' (length=3)
```

Comment: All I know is that the closure will return an object, and I want to know the parent class of the object which will be returned by the closure, but I do not want to instantiate it the object.

Comment: Why you don't want to make a new instance of a class? Do you need a parent class method to some validation? Isn't it enough to use class inheritance?

Comment: Because the class will not be used, and I don't want the class to record anything as I only want to know the parent of it. Is there a way to create a class without calling the constructor ?

Comment: Constructor method is called on each newly-created object if exists. You can possibly create a new class which extends previous one and in this case a constructor will not be called implicitly.

Comment: Yes, but by cloning `$closure()`, I will call `$closure()`. Therefore, I will just do `get_parent_class($closure())`, which will call `Bar`.

Comment: And you can create a class without calling its constructor with the [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor` method](http://php.net/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor).